# How to make flow layout centered?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

My goal is to display a few divs of the same size which are put in a parent div, no size specified.

Now it works fine. For example, with 1920x1080 resolution, I got 4 in a row. With 1366x768, I got 3 in a row.

The problem now is that, every row is left aligned. So if the space left in the right is not enought for a div, it will be just there, a big space.

How to make the divs in a row be centered, I mean the spaces of left and right are the same, no matter how many divs are there, in a row.

Comment: Can you show existing codes?

Comment: I don't think there's a css-only way of doing it

Comment: Are you actually using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, you can do this by using a `wrapper div`, `display:inline-block` and `text-align: center` on nested elements, here is a quick fiddle for you:

I have center aligned the parent (with margin auto), but it is not necessary to center align the child divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/qWEGm/

Comment: It is possible to center floated element but as Lee states it's better to use inline or inline-block.

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/centered.html